# BigNumber error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, solidity-0.5.x

I started learning solidity but when I use construct im getting the error, please help:
here's the code

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract base{

    uint data;
    constructor (uint _data) public {
        data = _data;

    }
    function getData() public view returns(uint) {
        return data;
    }

}
```

> Error - creation of Base errored: Error encoding arguments: Error:
> invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="",
> code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your contract works fine. As the two previous replies mentioned, you're "deploying" your contract with a **void input**. In other words, you haven't specified the value of your `data`.

type any `uint` value in "deploy" section and it will work fine.

[image]

All the best.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
You need to input value when you deploy the contract.

Answer (score 2):

The error is not on your smart contract, by the way, you're calling your constructor with "", try with numbers instead, e.g, "123", 123, 0...